# Constrained least squares

Tags: optimization, least-squares, constraints

Suppose that the least squares problem

$$\min_x \| Ax-b \|$$

has a unique solution $x^*$. Now, when we consider the constrained version such as

${\rm min}_x$ $\parallel Ax-b\parallel$ s.t. $x_i \leq 0$, $i=1,2,\dotsc,n$ (every $n$ element in vector $x$) can we say, without loss of generality that, there exists a solution for the constrained problem, only if the solution of the unconstrained problem $x^*$ lies inside the constraint set ? Or am I missing something?

My question is, if the unconstrained problem has a unique (one and only one possible) solution $x^*$ and if the feasible set derived with respect to the newly added constraint ($x_i \leq 0$, $i=1,2,\dotsc,n$ ) to the problem, does not include the "only possible =unique solution" of the unconstrained problem (${\rm min}_x$ $\parallel Ax-b\parallel$), then doesnt it mean that there does not exist a solution for the constrained problem?

Comment: 1.) Are you aware that you appear to be using $\leq$ on a vector $x$? 2.) I don't see any justification for your statement/assumption (cf. Kuhn/Tucker, where the solution often lies on the border of the constrained set).

Comment: @GDumphart  thank you for your thought on the problem, I have clarified the question. Please see the edited version. Thank you

Comment: @GDumphart it is standard practice to apply inequality operators to vectors in an elementwise fashion.

Comment: But to the OP: no, your reasoning is incorrect. The modified, constrained problem *does* have a solution; but it's different than the unconstrained solution.

Comment: @MichaeI agree that the modified constrained problem has a different solution than the unconstrained case 90. But I do not follow, how is it justified intuitively. This is an issue with my understanding I guess.

Comment: @MichaelGrant  my question is if the only possible solution of $\parallel Ax-b\parallel$ is not in the constrained set,how can the constrained problem have a solution? infeasible solution right??....but i think, with  least squares minimization, which is necessarily finding $x$ that makes  $Ax\to b$, there is some pecularity that can be explained. I dont get it yet.

Comment: What do you mean by "the only possible solution"? That is just an expression, which has a value for any value of X. In the unconstrained case you look for a value of X that makes that expression as small as possible. In the constrained case, you do exactly the same thing, only the search is restricted.